# useContext TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to code a shared to-do lists app and am currently facing some errors, since using useContext. I added App.js, ListContext which should fetch the data from firebase and List which is the child. I also tried, I hope correctly, useRef but it did not work either. Please help.

[image: Error]

ListContext.jsx

```
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import {
  collection,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  getDocs,
  query,
  updateDoc,
  where,
} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { db } from '../../firebase.config';

const ListContext = createContext({});

export const ListProvider = ({ children }) => {
  //USER AUTH INFO
  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser.uid;

  // LIST INFO
  const { listId } = useParams();
  const [list, setList] = useState({});
  const [listExtra, setListExtra] = useState({ owner: false });

  // UTILS
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  // FETCH LIST DATA
  const fetchListData = async () => {
    window.alert('trst');
    setLoading(true);
    const docRef = doc(db, 'lists', listId);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    // Check if List exists
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      // Checks if you can view this list Owner or Shared to you
      if (
        docSnap.data().userRef !== user &&
        !docSnap.data().sharedPeople?.includes(user)
      ) {
        toast.error('Du kannst diese Liste nicht einsehen.');
        navigate('/');
      }
      // SET LIST DATA
      setList(docSnap.data());

      // SET TRUE OR FALSE IF OWNER
      setListExtra({
        owner: docSnap.data().userRef === auth.currentUser.uid,
      });
    }

    // FETCH SHARED PEOPLES DATA
    docSnap.data().sharedPeople?.length > 0
      ? fetchSharedUserInfo(docSnap.data())
      : setLoading(false);
  };

  const fetchSharedUserInfo = async (data) => {
    setLoading(true);

    // Sets Query for fetching user data
    const docRef = collection(db, 'users');
    const q = query(docRef, where('userRef', 'in', data.sharedPeople));
    const querySnap = await getDocs(q);

    // Loops trough every shared person
    querySnap.forEach((el) => {
      // Setting user data for add user -> mapping through later
      setListExtra((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        sharedPeopleData: el.data(),
      }));
    });

    setLoading(false);
  };

  const processSharedAvatars = () => {
    if (list.sharedPeopleData?.length > 0) {
      let MAX_SHOWN =
        3 < list.sharedPeopleData.length ? 3 : list.sharedPeopleData.length;
      let svUser = [...list.sharedPeopleData];

      let users = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < MAX_SHOWN; i++) {
        users.push(svUser[i]);
      }

      return users;
    }

    return [];
  };

  const uploadSharedLists = async (addedUser) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const docRef = doc(db, 'lists', listId);

      let userRefsList = [];

      addedUser?.forEach((el) => {
        userRefsList.push(el.userRef);
      });

      listExtra.sharedPeopleData?.forEach((el) => {
        userRefsList.push(el.userRef);
      });

      // //setList(()[...userRefsList]);
      // setList((prev) => ({
      //   ...prev,
      //   sharedPeople: [...userRefsList],
      // }));

      // setListExtra((prev) => ({...prev, ...userRefsList}));

      await updateDoc(docRef, {
        sharedPeople: userRefsList,
      });
      fetchListData();
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(error);
    }
  };

  const removeSavedUser = (e) => {
    const comparekey = e;

    const remSharedUser = listExtra.sharedPeopleData.filter(
      (item) => item.email !== comparekey
    );

    setListExtra({ sharedPeopleData: { ...remSharedUser } });
  };

  return (
    <ListContext.Provider
      value={{
        auth,
        user,
        list,
        loading,
        setLoading,
        fetchListData,
        processSharedAvatars,
        uploadSharedLists,
        removeSavedUser,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ListContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ListContext;
```

List.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { db } from '../firebase.config';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { where, query, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import Spinner from '../components/Spinner';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import TaskList from '../components/TaskList';
import { ReactComponent as ChevronLeft } from '../assets/bx-chevron-left.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ShareIcon } from '../assets/bxs-share-alt.svg';
import EditMenuDropdown from '../components/EditMenuDropdown';
import EditListModal from '../components/modals/EditListModal';
import DeleteListModal from '../components/modals/DeleteListModal';
import LeaveListModal from '../components/modals/LeaveListModal';
import ListContext from '../components/contexts/ListContext';

function List() {
  const {
    auth,
    user,
    list,
    listExtra,
    loading,
    setLoading,
    processSharedAvatars,
    uploadSharedLists,
    removeSavedUser,
  } = useContext(ListContext);

  // Teilen
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  // Share Input Field
  const [shareInput, setShareInput] = useState('');
  // Badge -> Data
  const [addedUser, setAddedUser] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(123);

    // fetchListData();
    // const start = async () => {
    //   await fetchListData();
    // };
    // start();
  }, []);

  const onAdd = async () => {
    // Input nach Adden clearen
    setShareInput('');
    // Handling error sharing list to oneself
    if (auth.currentUser.email === shareInput) {
      toast.warn('Du kannst dich nicht selber hinzufügen');
      return;
    }
    // Handling error adding one person multiple times
    let double = false;
    addedUser.forEach((e) => {
      if (e.email === shareInput) {
        toast.error('Du kannst eine Person nicht mehrfach hinzufügen');
        double = true;
        return;
      }
    });
    listExtra.sharedPeopleData.forEach((e) => {
      if (e.email === shareInput) {
        toast.error('Du kannst eine Person nicht mehrfach hinzufügen');
        double = true;
        return;
      }
    });
    if (double) return;
    try {
      // GET userRef by Email
      const usersRef = collection(db, 'users');
      const q = query(usersRef, where('email', '==', shareInput));
      const querySnap = await getDocs(q);
      let found = [];
      querySnap.forEach((element) => {
        found.push(element.data());
      });

      console.log(found[0]);

      if (found.length > 0) {
        setAddedUser((prev) => [...prev, found[0]]);
        console.log(addedUser);
      } else {
        toast.error('Dieser Account existiert nicht!');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error('Dieser Account existiert nicht!');
    }
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setShareInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const clearModal = () => {
    setShareInput('');
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  const removeUserWhileAdding = (e) => {
    const comparekey = e;
    setAddedUser((prevState) =>
      prevState.filter((item) => item.email !== comparekey)
    );
  };

  if (loading) return <Spinner />;

  return (
    <>
      <div className="hero min-h-screen bg-base-200 w-screen">
        <div className="hero-content flex-col w-full">
          <div className="card flex-shrink-0 md:w-5/6 w-full overflow-x-hidden">
            <div className="card-body bg-base-100 ">
              <div className="heading w-full">
                <div className="flex w-full justify-between items-center">
                  <Link to="/lists">
                    <ChevronLeft className="w-20 h-20 -ml-5 fill-gray-500 inline" />
                  </Link>
                  <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
                    <div className="avatar-group -space-x-4 mx-4">
                      {processSharedAvatars().map((el) => (
                        <div className="avatar" key={el.userRef}>
                          <div
                            className="w-8"
                            style={{ background: `url(${el.url})` }}
                          ></div>
                        </div>
                      ))}

                      {list.sharedPeople?.length > 3 && (
                        <div className="avatar placeholder">
                          <div className="w-8 bg-neutral-focus text-white">
                            <span className="font-bold">
                              +{list.sharedPeople.length - 3}
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <ShareIcon
                      onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
                      className="fill-secondary w-10 h-10 cursor-pointer mr-4"
                    />
                    {/* MODAL */}
                    {!loading && <EditMenuDropdown owner={listExtra.owner} />}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold">{list.title}</h1>
                <div className="badges mt-2">
                  {list.sharedPeople?.length > 0 && (
                    <div className="badge badge-secondary mr-1">SHARED</div>
                  )}
                  {list.sharedPeople?.includes(user) && (
                    <div className="badge badge-info mr-1">FREMD</div>
                  )}
                  {list.sharedPeople?.length > 0 && list.userRef === user && (
                    <div className="badge badge-accent">OWNER</div>
                  )}
                </div>
                <p className="py-2 text-sm text-gray-500">{list.description}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="content overflow-x-hidden">
                <h1 className="text-xl font-bold">ToDos:</h1>
                <TaskList todos={list.todos} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className={`modal ${showModal && 'modal-open'}`}>
          <div className="modal-box relative">
            <button
              className="btn btn-sm btn-circle absolute right-2 top-2 text-white"
              onClick={clearModal}
            >
              ✕
            </button>
            <h3 className="text-2xl">
              Liste <p className="font-bold inline text-secondary">Teilen</p>
            </h3>
            <form onSubmit={() => {}} className="form-control mt-2 mb-8">
              <label htmlFor="email" className="label">
                <span>Mit wem möchtest du deine Liste teilen?</span>
              </label>
              <div className="input-group">
                <input
                  className="input input-bordered w-full"
                  type="email"
                  id="shareInput"
                  value={shareInput}
                  placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse"
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                  required
                />
                <div className="btn btn-info md:btn-md" onClick={() => onAdd()}>
                  Hinzufügen
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <p
                  className={`mb-1 ${
                    listExtra.sharedPeopleData &&
                    listExtra.sharedPeopleData?.length > 0
                      ? 'block'
                      : 'hidden'
                  }`}
                >
                  Aktuelle geteilte Benutzer:
                </p>
                {Array.isArray(listExtra.sharedPeopleData) &&
                  listExtra.sharedPeopleData?.length > 0 &&
                  listExtra.sharedPeopleData.map((sharedUser) => (
                    <div
                      className="badge badge-secondary badge-lg mr-2 mb-2"
                      key={sharedUser.email}
                    >
                      <div
                        className="mr-2 cursor-pointer"
                        onClick={() => removeSavedUser(sharedUser.email)}
                      >
                        ✕
                      </div>
                      <div
                        className="mr-1 h-5 w-5 bg-white rounded-full border shadow"
                        style={{ background: `url(${sharedUser.url})` }}
                      ></div>
                      {`${sharedUser.firstName} (${sharedUser.email})`}
                    </div>
                  ))}
              </div>
              <div className="mt-1">
                <p
                  className={`mb-1 ${
                    addedUser && addedUser?.length > 0 ? 'block' : 'hidden'
                  }`}
                >
                  Neu hinzugefügte Benutzer: (Bitte Speichern)
                </p>
                {Array.isArray(addedUser) &&
                  addedUser?.length > 0 &&
                  addedUser.map((sharedUser) => (
                    <div
                      className="badge badge-accent badge-lg mr-2 mb-2"
                      key={sharedUser.email}
                    >
                      <div
                        className="mr-2 cursor-pointer"
                        onClick={() => removeUserWhileAdding(sharedUser.email)}
                      >
                        ✕
                      </div>
                      <div
                        className="mr-1 h-5 w-5 bg-white rounded-full border shadow"
                        style={{ background: `url(${sharedUser.url})` }}
                      ></div>
                      {`${sharedUser.firstName} (${sharedUser.email})`}
                    </div>
                  ))}
              </div>
            </form>

            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-success md:btn-md btn-sm"
              onClick={uploadSharedLists}
            >
              Speichern
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="absolute hidden top-0 left-0 bg-green-100 w-screen h-screen z-10"></div>
      <DeleteListModal />
      <EditListModal />
      <LeaveListModal />
    </>
  );
}

export default List;
```

App.js

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Navigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.jsx';
import Overview from './pages/Overview.jsx';
import SwitchTheme from './components/SwitchTheme';
import Signup from './pages/Signup.jsx';
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound.jsx';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute.jsx';
import List from './pages/List.jsx';
import SharedLists from './pages/SharedLists.jsx';
import Profile from './pages/Profile.jsx';
import LoggedInRouter from './components/LoggedInRouter';
import Forgot from './pages/Forgot.jsx';
import DeleteListModal from './components/modals/DeleteListModal.jsx';
import { ModalProvider } from './components/contexts/ModalContext.jsx';
import { ListProvider } from './components/contexts/ListContext.jsx';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <SwitchTheme />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/lists" />} />
            <Route
              path="/lists"
              element={
                <>
                  <Overview />
                  <Navbar />
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/list/:listId"
              element={
                <>
                  <ListProvider>
                    <ModalProvider>
                      <List />
                    </ModalProvider>
                  </ListProvider>
                  <Navbar />
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/shared-lists"
              element={
                <>
                  <SharedLists /> <Navbar />
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/profile"
              element={
                <>
                  <Profile />
                  <Navbar />
                </>
              }
            />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/" element={<LoggedInRouter />}>
            <Route path="/sign-up" element={<Signup />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/forgot" element={<Forgot />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/404" element={<NotFound />} />
          <Route path="/*" element={<NotFound />} />
          <Route path="/test" element={<DeleteListModal />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <ToastContainer theme="colored"></ToastContainer>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Components are simpler if they do 1 thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**listExtra** is missing in your Conxtext Provder component

```
value={{
  auth,
  user,
  list,
  //add listExtra here (inside ListContext.Provider values)
  loading,
  setLoading,
  fetchListData,
  processSharedAvatars,
  uploadSharedLists,
  removeSavedUser,
}}
```